# What is the mechanism of GIT merging?

Tags: android, git, version-control, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm novice learner of GIT. i'm developing a social networking app. with a friend on Android which is a significantly massive project, so in order to synchronize our development, i decided to use Version Controlling. Now my project is on BitBucket. i'm decided not to waste time on command line and started using "SourceTree" to manage. Now i've certain confusion. i understand the fundamentals of Commits, push , fetch , branching etc. My question is :

Lets say, both me and my friend are working on different activities in our development branches of app. and making commits , but there are some files common to us , like Manifest.xml , build.gradle etc.. so when these branches are merged to "Production/Master" , how will the changes in these "common" files will get accommodated ? what if we both added code to a certain file and arrangement of lines of code matters , then how the merging mechanism will gives us a working project with integrated modules , if i'm wrong with my basic concepts, feel free to correct and suggest me some reference material. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you and your friend modify the same file. When you do the merge could happen 2 things:

1. If both of you modify the same file in different regions of code. Git is capable to do the merge without conflicts.
2. If both of you modify the same file in the same regions of code. Git will do the merge with conflicts.

If the file has conflicts, it will looks like this:

```
... Some code ...
<<<<<<< HEAD
   Line added by you
-------
   Line added by your friend
>>>>>>> branch_name
... More code ...
```

You need to decide which of the two lines (Line added by you and line added by your friend) has the correct code. Then, delete the line that has the wrong code and the following lines:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
-------
>>>>>>> branch_name
```

If you want, you can setup a tool to resolve conflicts like p4merge. You can download it from:

[p4merge for Windows 64 bits](http://cdist2.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/bin.ntx64/p4vinst64.exe)

[p4merge for Windows 32 bits](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/perforce/r15.1/bin.ntx86/p4vinst.exe)

[p4merge for other OS](http://www.perforce.com/downloads/helix#product-10)

You install this tool and then you need to setup with this git commands:

```
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path 'C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe'
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
```

To verify if all is right. Your .gitconfig file `(C:\Users\windows_user\.gitconfig)` will look like this:

```
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
```

After you have run the `git merge` command. To resolve conflicts using p4merge, you need to execute the `git mergetool` command. It opens the p4merge tool and show the conflicts like this image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When the same file is being modified in two different instance and then merges, there are two possible outcomes. If the code that is modified in in the files are in different sections, Git will merge the two files. If both files modify the same section of the code then Git will give you a merge conflict, which you will then have to resolve.

The following link goes over the details of resolving merge conflicts.
https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/

Another option that should be looked at is rebasing.
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/conceptual-overview

Answer (score 1):

Merges are done via a couple of different mechanisms.  The default usually works well, particularly for smaller teams.  When things get larger then one of the other algorithms can be more effective.  If there are areas touched by both parties, they are flagged as conflicts and you must manually resolve.  I suggest reading the Git book for more details and examples:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging